# Why does my Java method redirect without using any Intent?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to debug the following code. My problem is that I store data to the Firebase real-time database but upon successful completion, my current activity automatically redirects to another activity without using of any Intent. How can I figure out the problem? I am attaching my Java method to get a clear idea of it.

```
private void uploadTextData(String universityname, String studentregistrationnumber, String ten, String twelve, String graduation, String currentacademic, String keyskills, String uriPath) {
    addStudentDetailsData.setCurrentAcademic("currentacademic: "+ currentacademic.replace("%",""));
    addStudentDetailsData.setGraduation("graduation: " + graduation.replace("%",""));
    addStudentDetailsData.setImageUrl("uriPath: " + uriPath);
    String key = universityname + " " + studentregistrationnumber;
    addStudentDetailsData.setKey("key: " + key);
    addStudentDetailsData.setKeySkills("keyskills: " + keyskills);
    addStudentDetailsData.setTen("ten: " + ten.replace("%",""));
    addStudentDetailsData.setTwelve("twelve: " + twelve.replace("%",""));
    addStudentDetailsData.setUniversityName("universityname:" + universityname);
    addStudentDetailsData.setStudentRegistrationNumber("studentregistrationnumber: " + studentregistrationnumber);
    addStudentDetailsData.setStudentName("studentname: " + studentname.getText().toString().trim());
    addStudentDetailsData.setContactNumber("contactnumber: " + contactnumber.getText().toString().trim());
    addStudentDetailsData.setEmailId("emailid: " + emailid.getText().toString().trim());
    addStudentDetailsData.setSelectedBranch("selectedBranch: " + selectedBranch);
    addStudentDetailsData.setDob("date: " + date);
    if (!selectedSemester.equals("Choose your current semester")) {
        addStudentDetailsData.setSemester("Semester: " + selectedSemester);
    }
    else Toast.makeText(this, "Please choose a correct semester", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ref1= database1.getInstance().getReference().child("Upload Student Details");
    ref1.child(key).setValue(addStudentDetailsData);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Data uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    AlertDialog.Builder a11= new AlertDialog.Builder(AddStudentDetails.this);
    a11.setTitle("Message");
    a11.setMessage("Data uploaded successfully");
    a11.setCancelable(false);
    a11.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog a1= a11.create();
    a1.show();
}
```

Comment: Hello here, I am not using any Intent class to redirect to other Activity but its automatically goes to the another activity, I am unable to figure out the reason for it, please help me to debug this problem.

Comment: Were you in the activity you get redirected to before or did it start completely new? Please show a bit more of your code!

Comment: No the app got redirected to the update activity every time while I upload any data to the firebase.